# Will bombing the donation machine re-lock already unlocked items?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

If I've got the donation machine to 999 will bombing for coins it relock the Stop Watch, or do unlocks stay unlocked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [Rebirth Wiki](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Donation_Machine) states:

> When the amount of coins donated increases past 999, the machine will explode, dropping roughly 12 dimes and resetting the total to 0.
>
> **Nothing unlocked through donations will be lost if the amount of coins in the donation machine is reduced in any way**. Thus once something is unlocked it can never be locked again.

Comment: Why a downvote?

Answer (score 5):

**No**.

Once something, shop or other, has been unlocked, it will never be "re-locked".

This does not only apply to the 999 cent barrier, but to the earlier ones as well (Blue/Red/Black Candle, etc..)